# Tenacious-Silver vs Unsung Hero-Gold

Tags: discussion, badges

Here are two peculiar badges that have never been earned:
[image]

Question is, why is there a gold badge, at this slightly-advanced stage, with double the requirement of a silver badge that for all intents and purposes, would be a *lofty* and improbable gold badge in difficulty?

The concern is: the increasing population may counter the increasing efforts of senior users, as more users means more votes, countering likelihood of 'zero-score accepteds'.

There is a fair chance that someone could ever earn a 'Tenacious', but... Unsung Hero- can't see it.

Should Tenacious be elevated to gold, and Unsung removed?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those badges that is fairly easy to get on SO, but not at all possible to get on most sites. As you noticed, there isn't even a single user to have the Tenacious badge, and a relatively few Tumbleweed badges.

Actually, sites exploding in popularity actually makes getting these badges more likely. It takes users who up vote a lot of questions to not have the votes to upvote one, but they accept one anyways. It isn't likely to ever get the badge here, but it might as well be left here, for the day that someone is able to get them.